Magento 2 : Integrate Javascript based Payment Gateway
I have a requirement for payment gateway integration. The payment gateway is completely built with javascript (example : Izipay [https://developers.izipay.pe/web-core/]).
So how can I integrate such type of payment gateways in magento 2.4.6.
Any help much appreciated.

On your gateway documentation,
they give you redirect payment gatway options, which you can implement same like other payment method.
You can check this : https://developers.izipay.pe/web-core/modalidades/redirect/
